# No sound after update to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I very recently made the switch to Ubantu, mainly to eradicate corporations from my life. But also to learn Linux and understand the underbelly of technology. I love everything about it, except my speakers stopped working when I updated from 20.04. My headphones work, but no sound otherwise. Audio is showing up as generic. I've spent days troubleshooting but each case seems unique and I'm new to the intricacies.

Please help if you can. This is what I'm working with:

```
aplay -l


card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC245 Analog [ALC245 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

---

```
aplay -L


null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
samplerate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
oss
    Open Sound System
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
upmix
    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
    Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
hw:CARD=Generic,DEV=3
    HD-Audio Generic, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Generic,DEV=7
    HD-Audio Generic, HDMI 1
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Generic,DEV=3
    HD-Audio Generic, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Generic,DEV=7
    HD-Audio Generic, HDMI 1
    Hardware device with all software conversions
hdmi:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=Generic,DEV=1
    HD-Audio Generic, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Generic,DEV=3
    HD-Audio Generic, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Generic,DEV=7
    HD-Audio Generic, HDMI 1
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=Generic
    HD-Audio Generic
    USB Stream Output
hw:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC245 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC245 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=Generic_1
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC245 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC245 Analog
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC245 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC245 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC245 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC245 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC245 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC245 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
dmix:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC245 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=Generic_1
    HD-Audio Generic
    USB Stream Output
```

---

```
lspci -v

04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 69, IOMMU group 14
    Memory at d05c8000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

```
04:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 84, IOMMU group 18
    Memory at d0580000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x, snd_pci_acp5x, snd_pci_acp6x
```

```
04:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 58, IOMMU group 19
    Memory at d05c0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

If I'm missing anything **please let me know**. Maybe it's an easy fix, but this is just a bit too advanced for me at this stage in the game.